# Can I create a pop up window upon completion of uploading of files in django

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have some files that have large sizes that will be uploaded to http://127.0.0.1:8000/, so it will take some time. I was just wondering: how do I make a pop up window on upon completion in django?  Will it be possible? Be it javascript or html? If it is possible, can anyone show and explain the codes to me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to implement sweetify library into django under views.py and it serves as a pop up window and works just fine :)

Link: https://github.com/Atrox/sweetify-django